# Regex to find second occurrence of a domain within a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract the second occurrence of a web domain in a string with regex within Google App Script. In the below example you can see it is returning duckduckgo.com and chicaspoderosas.org

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="//duckduckgo.com/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fchicaspoderosas.org%2Fabout%2F&amp;rut=6df21641031fd7b57d82fcdbc2312bc4b27034927655759d8e270840fae4fab1">ABOUT - Chicas Poderosas</a>
```

I can do it no problem when the second domain has a subdomain such as www with the below regex, but can't seem to get the target extraction right when there isn't a subdomain on the second domain.

Current one that works when subdomain is present:

```
var regExp = new RegExp("(www.[a-z]+.[a-z]+.[a-z])", "gi");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not too clear. Please provide accurate examples of what's working and what's not and should be working with the regex shown above. E.g. I see you're matching always against `www` but there's no `www` in any of the domains above. List as many possible input combinations as you can, unless it's "anything goes" and it can be all sorts of URLs and formats like `ftp://` or just plain domain without even a protocol. Very likely though URL parsing is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start matching the href followed by 2 times the possible url format that is in the example string and use a capture group (where the value is in group 1) for the second url that you want to get.

Assuming that the `//` is the start of an url in the example data:

```
\bhref="(?:https?(?:%3A|:))?(?:%2F%2F|\/\/)[^\s"]*?((?:https?(?:%3A|:))?(?:%2F%2F|\/\/)[^\s"]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/etLDWe/1)